# SQL Error The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I'm trying to execute this query, I get "The multi-part identifier "#EachEmployee.ResultID" could not be bound." error.

```
DECLARE @QueryText VARCHAR(1000) 
SET @QueryText = '
UPDATE #EachEmployee2 
SET #EachEmployee2.CorrectAnswerCount = (
    SELECT COUNT (TMID)
    FROM 
        ' + @WorkDatabaseName + '.dbo.TestBlockTM AS TBTM, 
        ' + @WorkDatabaseName + '.dbo.TestResultTM AS TRTM
    WHERE 1 = 1
          AND TBTM.TMID = TRTM.OtvetID
          AND TBTM.TMPID = TRTM.VoprosID
          AND TRTM.TestResultID = #EachEmployee2.ResultID
    ) 
WHERE
    #EachEmployee2.IsGroup = 0 AND #EachEmployee2.BlockID = 1'
EXECUTE(@QueryText)
```

However, the similar query is working perfectly:

```
UPDATE #EachEmployee2 
SET #EachEmployee2.ResultID = (
SELECT TOP 1 TestResultID
FROM #AnswersList AS a
WHERE 1 = 1
      AND a.SID = #EachEmployee2.SID 
      AND a.UserID = #EachEmployee2.UserID
)
```

Can someone tell what's a problem here? Thanks and appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SET @QueryText = '
UPDATE emp
SET emp.CorrectAnswerCount = (
    SELECT COUNT (TMID)
    FROM 
        ' + @WorkDatabaseName + '.dbo.TestBlockTM AS TBTM, 
        ' + @WorkDatabaseName + '.dbo.TestResultTM AS TRTM
    WHERE 1 = 1
          AND TBTM.TMID = TRTM.OtvetID
          AND TBTM.TMPID = TRTM.VoprosID
          AND TRTM.TestResultID = emp.ResultID
    ) 
    From #EachEmployee2 emp
WHERE
    emp.IsGroup = 0 AND emp.BlockID = 1'
```

Comment: This is helped. To be honest, I didn't know that you can use FROM after "UPDATE..SET.." expression. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this query and tell me if the error still occurs:

```
SET @QueryText = '
UPDATE #EachEmployee2 
SET CorrectAnswerCount = (
    SELECT COUNT (TMID)
    FROM 
        ' + @WorkDatabaseName + '.dbo.TestBlockTM AS TBTM, 
    INNER JOIN ' + @WorkDatabaseName + '.dbo.TestResultTM AS TRTM ON TRTM.OtvetID = TBTM.TMID
                                                                    AND TRTM.VoprosID = TBTM.TMPID
                                                                    AND TRTM.TestResultID = E.ResultID
    ) 
FROM #EachEmployee2 E
WHERE E.IsGroup = 0
    AND E.BlockID = 1'
```

I added the `FROM` clause and modified a bit the subquery in order to replace the old SQL syntax by an explicit `INNER JOIN` clause.

Hope this will help